# Difference between JavaFX node and UI component?

Tags: javafx

What is the difference between JavaFX node and a UI component?

I understand that the both concepts are similar but I am sure that there is a reason why we call a JavaFX Node a node and not a Component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly, node is a general element in a scene tree. Component as generaly understood is a composition of several nodes (in JavaFX) enriched with behavior of some kind. In JavaFX we do not have components. We rather called them controls.